# SignInManager without the Lock Out features

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity

I'll keep this short: I need to sign my users in but my custom UserStore doesn't interface the lock out functionality that is required to use the SignInManager. Basically, I need a SignInManager which doesn't check the Lock Out logic.

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe);
```

That is essentially what I need to be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

So to solve this I've been a bit dirty and left some unimplemented methods..

I implemented `IUserLockoutStore<User, string>` and `IUserTwoFactorStore<User, string>` then just returned `false` on both methods which get called during `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`

```
    public Task<int> GetAccessFailedCountAsync(User user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<bool> GetLockoutEnabledAsync(User user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<bool>(false);
    }

    public Task<DateTimeOffset> GetLockoutEndDateAsync(User user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<int> IncrementAccessFailedCountAsync(User user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(User user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task SetLockoutEnabledAsync(User user, bool enabled)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task SetLockoutEndDateAsync(User user, DateTimeOffset lockoutEnd)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<bool> GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(User user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<bool>(false);
    }

    public Task SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(User user, bool enabled)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```